# which one is better in both use of JOIN in sql query or stored function in the query?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have following tables:

1. student (stuID, classId, addId ,name)

2. student_address (addId, stuId, city, state)
3. student_hobby (stuId, hobby )
4. student_class (classId, stuId, className)

I have two options:- 
 One option is: 
query to get all detail of the student using join:-

```
select s.name, sd.city, sc.className
from student as s join student_address sd on s.addId = sd.addId 
inner join student_class sc on sc.classId = s.classId 
inner join student_hobby sh on sh.stuId = s.stuId
where sh.hobby REGEXP 'cricket|footbal';
```

another option is using stored function:

```
select s.name, sd.city, sc.className
from student as s join student_address sd on s.addId = sd.addId 
inner join student_class sc on sc.classId = s.classId 
where f_searchHobby(s.stuId,'cricket|footbal')=1;
```

```
create function f_searchHobby( 
sId int,
matches varchar(100)
 ) returns int 
begin
 select count(*) into @count from student_hobby where hobby regexp matches and stuId = sId;
 if @count > 1 then
  return 1 ;
 else 
  return 0; 
 end if; 
end
```

Consider both result are getting resultset.
So let me suggest which approach will work better for heavy database.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored function example you should is going to execute a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query *for each row* of the outer query.  This is equivalent to a *correlated subquery*, and it's terrible for performance.

The REGEXP example you should is also bad, but not as bad as the stored function.  The REGEXP can't use an index, it will always required a table-scan, applying the expression to every row of the table.

It would be better for the search you show to use an `IN( )` predicate:

```
select s.name, sd.city, sc.className
from student as s join student_address sd on s.addId = sd.addId 
inner join student_class sc on sc.classId = s.classId 
inner join student_hobby sh on sh.stuId = s.stuId
where sh.hobby IN ('cricket', 'footbal');
```

That assumes that each hobby is stored individually on a separate row.

If you are storing a list of hobbies in a string on one row, then you should use a [FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html):

```
select s.name, sd.city, sc.className
from student as s join student_address sd on s.addId = sd.addId 
inner join student_class sc on sc.classId = s.classId 
inner join student_hobby sh on sh.stuId = s.stuId
where MATCH(sh.hobby) AGAINST ('cricket footbal' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Thanks Bill Karwin,
I agree with you for both suggestions but suppose I have two hobbies like listening Music, listening songs. and my requirement is only passing the keyword 'listening' in where clause and if I am not using mYISAM. then what I should do for both result listening music and listening songs?

Comment: I didn't follow that and I'm not going to guess what you mean.  Please post another question, post your table definitions (output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`) and the query you want to run.  Even better if you create a demo on http://sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: And for what it's worth, MySQL 5.6 supports fulltext indexes in InnoDB.  Otherwise use [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/), it's far faster than MySQL's fulltext indexes.